# Removing an element in an array and shifting the elements left to close the gap

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

Here is the code that I have.  The function is supposed to remove a string in an array of strings and then shift all the elements left to close the gap.

```
void removeWord(char ***array, int *count){

    char word[41];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fscanf(stdin, " ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", word);
    bool wordFound = false;
    int indexOfWord = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < *count; i++){
            if(strcasecmp(word, (*array)[i]) == 0){
                    wordFound = true;
                    indexOfWord = i;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if(wordFound == false){
            fprintf(stderr, "Word not found in dictionary.\n");
    }
    else{
            free((*array)[indexOfWord]);
            // Decrement count
            (*count)--;
            for(int i = indexOfWord; i < *count; i ++){
                    // Shift elements over to the left by 1 to close the gap
                    (*array)[i] = (*array)[i+1];
            }
            // If the word to remove isn't the last element, remove the last element to prevent duplicate words
            if(indexOfWord != *count) free((*array)[*count]);

    }
}
```

When I remove the LAST word in the array, the function works properly...but when I remove the 2nd to last word, it removes it, but also sets the last element to some odd value/null.  I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while if anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated...Thanks, if more info is needed do not hesitate to ask.

-----------------------UPDATE

The answer was to delete the if statement at the end, it was unnecessary:

```
void removeWord(char ***array, int *count){

    char word[41];

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fscanf(stdin, " ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", word);
    bool wordFound = false;
    int indexOfWord = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < *count; i++){
            if(strcasecmp(word, (*array)[i]) == 0){
                    wordFound = true;
                    indexOfWord = i;
                    break;
            }
    }
    if(wordFound == false){
            fprintf(stderr, "Word not found in dictionary.\n");
    }
    else{
            free((*array)[indexOfWord]);
            // Decrement count
            (*count)--;
            for(int i = indexOfWord; i < *count; i ++){
                    // Shift elements over to the left by 1 to close the gap
                    (*array)[i] = (*array)[i+1];
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of your `else` your `free()` the word you wanted to delete. You then shift all remaining words over. The end result is that your `array[count-1]` (last valid element) and `array[count]` both contain the same pointer. You then free `array[count]`, making `array[count-1]` contain a pointer to freed memory.

Why the second `free()` at all? You wanted to delete 1 word, you `free()` that word and you're done.

Also, Why the `char *** array`? Everywhere you use it you're doing `(*array)` dereferencing it once. Why not pass the `char **` array of pointers into the function?

Comment: It's the same thing, just the way I wrote the code.  The point of this exercise is to become more familiarized with pointers and arrays, so i figured why not? The second free is to delete any duplicates.  If I removed the 5th element in a 7 element array and then shift to the left with my code.  The 7th and 6th element would both be the same value would they not?

Comment: I deleted that line and it now works, must have been going crazy when I wrote that....Thanks, works fine now.

Comment: @Riptyde4 Ahh, you need to understand the difference between a pointer and the actual data. The pointers would be duplicates, that is, you would have two pointers pointing to the same data on the heap, but only 1 copy of the actual data. When you do the `free()` it gets rid of the data, so anywhere with a pointer to it has a pointer to nothing. You are duplicating the pointer with the assignment, but not the data. You should probably be setting to `NULL` as well: `array[count] = NULL` at the end of the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with this code:

```
if(indexOfWord != *count) free((*array)[*count]);
```

Issue is due to, you already decremented the `*count`, so now if you refer using modified `*count` value, it'll refer to the current actual last value.
Also no need to free the last element, because the current last element and previous last element points to same memory so, just set the pointer to `NULL`.

Change it to:

```
if(indexOfWord != *count) (*array)[((*count) + 1)] = NULL;
```

Comment: I made this change earlier, I get a bunch of invalid read of size 1 errors in valgrind, as well as an error stating Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s).
I also got a ==3862== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] on a separate execution

Comment: @Riptyde4: It should work, I edited the code a little bit. Check that too. If you get any error please add the error as comment. I'll try to help you.